# Convert time series data to features - panda way?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

I think the best explanation would be an input-output example of what I need (in links attached).

In words: I have a data frame with dates and values of some arrays A/B/C. and a result column (1/0 values).

I want to make new data frame.

1. The rows are dates.
2. the feature columns are of the kind: "the value of array A/B/C ,X
   months before current row date". where X can change on my demand.
3. The result column is 1 if there is 1 in the next or next next month
   in the original data frame.

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

I've tried stuff with lops and indexes but it just doesnt feel right... (nor working :()

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xayKv.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnCZp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pandas shift function: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html

It allows to shift values in a column.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And lol I used it a lot before. just did not think about it in that context. thanks!